# Foreach datagridview row actualizar stock

Tags: c#, sql

es posible actualizar un stock con procedimiento almacenado mediante un foreach
es decir tengo esta ejecucion de procedimiento:

```
                SqlConnection conec = new SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();
                cm.Connection = con;
                cm.CommandText = "SP_ActualizaInventario";
                cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cantidad", SqlDbType.Int));
                cm.Parameters["@cantidad"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Column13"].Value);

                cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Producto", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                cm.Parameters["@Producto"].Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column7"].Value);

                cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Tipo", SqlDbType.Int));
                cm.Parameters["@Tipo"].Value = 1;
```

me va a tomar el valor de las columnas que indique para ejecutar el procedimiento pero el procedimiento al parecer no toma cada linea sino la ultima linea solamente  como lo arreglo? lo pongo dentro del foreach o fuera?

store procedure

```
     ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ActualizaInventario]
         @cantidad INT
,@Producto VARCHAR
,@Tipo INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Existencia INT
SET @Existencia = (SELECT Existencia FROM maestraproductoinventario WHERE [Codigo De Articulo] = @Producto)
if(@Tipo = 1)
begin
UPDATE
 maestraproductoinventario 
 SET
    Existencia = @Existencia - @cantidad 
    WHERE [Codigo De Articulo] = @Producto
end
else
begin
UPDATE
 maestraproductoinventario 
 SET
    Existencia = @Existencia + @cantidad 
    WHERE [Codigo De Articulo] = @Producto
end
END
```

Comment: Falta el código del Store Procedure.

Comment: ya lo edite @RobertoLeónOramas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día

Como la parte donde obtienes el `row.Cells["..."].value` parece ser que pueden existir varios te sugiero hacer un foreach o for (según se pueda en ese orden) para obtener cada elemento *cantidad* y *producto*; invocando:

```
public void actualizarStock(int laCantidad, string elProducto) {
   SqlConnection conec = new SqlConnection();
   SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand();

   cm.Connection = con;
   cm.CommandText = "SP_ActualizaInventario";
   cm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cantidad", SqlDbType.Int));
   cm.Parameters["@cantidad"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(laCantidad);

   cm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Producto", SqlDbType.VarChar));
   cm.Parameters["@Producto"].Value = Convert.ToString(elProducto);
} // actualizarStock
```

ejmplo (asumiendo funcionaria con foreach):

```
foreach(row fila in objetoconrow.Rows)
{
    actualizarStock(Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Column13"].Value), 
                    Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column7"].Value));
}
```

El Store Procedure:

```
[CREATE|ALTER] PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_ActualizaInventario]
   @cantidad INT
   ,@Producto VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN

    UPDATE maestraproductoinventario 
        SET
            Existencia = Existencia + @cantidad 
    WHERE [Codigo De Articulo] = @Producto;

END
```

> Notas:
>
> CREATE o ALTER según corresponda.
>
> @cantidad deberá recibir valor positivo si se incrementara o negativo si se decrementara (se recibe o sale del stock la cantidad de producto; lo que al parecer determina con @Tipo).
>
> En caso que quieras enviar todo en una sola invocación será realizar cambios al Store procedure para que reciba un array, mira este artículo que te servira [How to pass an array into a SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102358/how-to-pass-an-array-into-a-sql-server-stored-procedure)